# How to flag an off-topic question on a non-linux OS?

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons, flagging, scope

## The question

Since the new flags for closing (which I applaud) it is unclear to me how I can **flag a question about Windows**, Mac, Solaris or whatever which clearly does not belong here.

I want to flag [Back to Factory settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313417/back-to-factory-settings#comment396225_313417), but I can't actually flag just Off-Topic (see the disabled button on the screenshot below). We have to choose an option. If I choose "it belongs on another site in the SE network," I am forced to choose meta...

- Am I missing something?
- If not, should this be changed?

## A screenshot

[image: flagging closing off-topic]

Comment: My close dialogue looks different on that question. I have another option: "Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)".

Comment: @gertvdijk That could be because the reputation. I'm doing the same under a **question** and I get the same options that the OP.

Comment: Flagging for custom OT reason is not possible. Which is basically why I stopped bothering at this point.

Comment: @FEichinger Are you suggesting that we should stop close-voting off-topic questions like the one above and leave them to higher rep users?

Comment: @Private I'm not suggesting that, no. But there is no way to *flag* for generic/custom off-topic, without going through the global custom flag.

Comment: The new close system as pretty much made flagging useless, but no one listens.

Comment: MSO report: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186262/is-an-option-missing-in-the-new-off-topic-reasons

Comment: @Seth Thanks. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185873/195914 which basically says that you need 3k+ rep to get the "custom" off-topic close vote. Which explains why Private and I don't see the same dialogue.

Comment: @gertvdijk Hmm makes sense. The problem is: if you teach low rep users not to flag certain types of off-topic questions, they are likely to continue that behavior once they are higher rep users.

Comment: I believe Mac OSX and Solaris fit under "unix", although we should send OSX users to Ask Diffrent, http://kb.iu.edu/data/agjq.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X

Comment: Oddly enough when I flag this question as off topic (this question on meta) I get much nicer options. ("This question does not appear to be about on-topic, within the scope defined in the help center.") But I can't get that option on AskUbuntu

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that out of these, "Another site in the Stack Exchange network" works nicely for this. OSX + Solaris would (in part, at least) be covered by the scope of the Unix SE; most other operating system issues (Windows, and non-Unix-related things within OSX for instance) would go over to Super User.

I've not used any of the other SE sites so I could be wrong, but that's pretty much how the situation looks for me. Questions asked here but not under the scope of this precise site are probably going to be covered by one of the other sites, they just need to be given a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: The another site option only lets us choose meta right now... maybe that should be altered.

Comment: @Private Huh. Strange... I assumed it would be a generic "put it somewhere else" option, not "specify from this populated-with-only-one-item list"...
Although, actually it seems like I have access to the "Other (add a comment)" option too, which isn't shown in the screenshot above - so I doubt it's a rep thing, and actually I'm not sure what it is (unless it was stealth-added between your question being asked and now...)

Comment: Feature request here: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/6493/44179 (cc @Private)