# Why can't I migrate questions to other StackExchange sites?

Tags: support, migration

If on a question I click **close → Off topic because... → This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network**, I get just one option: [Ask Ubuntu Meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/).

How do I migrate, for example, to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Because we don't have migration paths...

Comment: Then why don't we have migration paths?

Comment: Nah I'm just kidding. I think the reason is because only moderators can migrate to other sites and have a full list of the sites (or maybe only the relevant ones), while we only get to vote to migrate to our own meta.

Comment: @Alaa That isn't so. When the migration paths are open 5 3k users can migrate questions to certain sites. However, these paths are closed on most sites and attempts to get them open have met moderator resistance.

Comment: See this question: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6493/cannot-specify-other-se-groups-for-transfer/6494#6494

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately you can't vote to migrate a question anywhere but meta. There are so called "migration paths" that would enable slots in the close dialog, but these "paths" have been closed for quite a while due to misuse of the feature in the early days of the site.

[Previous attempts](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6493/cannot-specify-other-se-groups-for-transfer/6494#6494) to have them opened have met with moderator resistance.

Comment: Ok suggestion: 2 new "review" options called "We would like to move  this topic to site Y". and "Do we want this topic from size Z". Moderators on site Z with X1 rep get to tag a topic to move and moderators on site Y with X2 rep get to vote to accept it. 5+ votes within X hours -> move + notification to user. Otherwise option to move gets blocked on site Z with a "rejected".

Comment: @Rinzwind I think that's a great idea!

Comment: @Rinzwind should you take that to [metase] ?