# Why can I only flag for a question to be migrated to Meta

Tags: discussion, migration

Why I had a look at the flagging as off-topic options for *'This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network'*, I only get Meta as an option:

[image]

Is it because it would be impractical to list the 120~ SW sites or something??

Comment: No, we can have up to 5 sites there, but they have never been enabled, [mainly for the reasons outlined here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8660/44179).

Comment: I was wondering about this due to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/486723/touchpad-problems-changes-to-50-synaptics-conf-dont-stick), which only says 'Debian-based' (it could be Linux Mint or anything... (but it does have some research and what they have tried etc)), so might belong elsewhere. @Seth - you could add that as an answer :-)

Comment: was my example correct, as it has since been migrated? :D

Comment: Yes your example was correct :)

Comment: Because nobody has poked a CM with a sharp stick so they get [this implemented](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8661/169736)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, we could have up to 5 sites in that list, allowing 3k users to migrate questions without the help of a moderator, but we have never requested they be enabled, [mainly for the reasons outlined here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8660/44179).

Comment: @Wilf No, it is entirely independent of rep. The feature is, currently, entirely disabled. For an example of what it would look like, if enabled, take [Super User for example](http://i.imgur.com/vdzKyaO.png).

Comment: Would an alternative be to flag for a moderator's attention (like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mg63C.png))? e.g. [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/490377/178596) which has 'Debian' written all over it. Flagging as off-topic seems pretty standard and doesn't get anywhere much of the time...

Comment: @Wilf Yes that works. If you think it is migration worthy (i.e. it isn't junk) go ahead and bump it up to us. Otherwise just vote to close normally. The reason that doesn't appear to get anywhere is because there are over 900 questions in the close vote queue. It takes a while to get through them all. Mentioning it in [chat] helps.