# What is wrong with migrating a question to another site?

Tags: discussion, migration

I understand that a lot of moderators on this site are against migrating questions to other SE sites (except for AU Meta, but that is part of AU, so don't really count), and I was just wondering why this was? Why is it better to close a question rather than to migrate it to a more relevant site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open migrations are awful. [That's my opinion](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8646/activate-migration-paths-to-unix-and-linux-should-we/8660#8660). They are a destructive way of quickly trying to push a person and their problem to another site, regardless of quality. They just don't help the people with the problem.

There are obviously exceptions, and they deserve flagging for moderator attention... But they are few enough that we can deal with them on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing intrinsically wrong with migrating a question, but in a lot of cases it can fall under the [don't migrate crap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225006/add-a-dont-migrate-crap-migration-path-to-all-sites) rule.